# Laravel DataTables change filters

Tags: php, laravel, yajra-datatable

Could not find a solution how to override Laravel DataTables behaviour.
I have a piece of code in front end:

```
var columnFilter = function(columnSelector, value) {
    $('.clear-filter').removeClass('active');
    clearFilter();
    table.column(columnSelector + ':name').search(value).draw();
    console.log(value);
}
```

The problem here is that it gives me a query with 'LIKE' :

```
 (where 'column' LIKE '%value%'.)
```

Is there a way to override this and use EQUALS instead of like?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you ask / search on the yajra-datatable repository or their documentation site https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/?

Comment: I have read all the documentation few times (not only this one), however, no solution was found.

Answer (score 1):

I found the filterColumn function to be where the query can be customized. For example:

```
return DataTables::eloquent($model)
            ->filterColumn('columName', function($query, $keyword) {
                $sql = "columnName = ?";
                $query->whereRaw($sql, [$keyword]);
            })
            ->toJson();
```

Ref. https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables-docs/blob/master/filter-column.md

Answer (score 0):

Have not found a way to do it properately. However, managed to make workaround using regular expressions.